# Mathematica failing to evaluate sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, sum

I have some sums to simplify/evaluate, but for some reason I can't even get Mathematica to simplify relatively simple sums. For example, I tried to get Mathematica to simplify this sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=k+1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+1}{r}$$

In this case, it is easy to prove that the sum is equal to $2^{2n}$.

I used `FullSimplify[Sum[Binomial[n, k]*Binomial[n + 1, r], {k, 0, n}, {r, k + 1, n + 1}]]`, but Mathematica returns this:

[image]

I can't make any sense of the output. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: **Maple 2024** also can't compute. Mathematica is not a **magic box** that'll spit out a solution to **any** problem. Try **AI** and see if he(she) answers correctly?

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sum[n_] = Sum[Binomial[n, k]*Binomial[n + 1, r], {k, 0, n}, {r, k + 1, n + 1}]
```

[image]

The result is a [`DifferenceRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html).

Generate a sequence and use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
sum2[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[sum /@ Range[6], n]

(* 4^n *)
```

Verifying the result outside of the range of the sequence,

```
And @@ Table[sum[n] == 4^n, {n, 0, 50}]

(* True *)
```

While `sum` is discrete, `sum2` is continuous.

```
FunctionDomain[sum2[n], n]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Can we compute  sum without use: `FindSequenceFunction` ?